# Prove: If $E$ is a non-empty subspace of $R^n$, then $f(x)=d(x,E)$ is continuous on $R^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I tried to take $x$ as $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, and similarly for $y$, which belongs to $E$. Then only need to get the $\delta$. But I just can't get the $\delta$ I want. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Just a writing tip: "If $E$ is a non-empty subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f(x)=d(x,E)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried to take $x,y \in E$ as $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n)$ and similarly for $y$." This is what your question should look like. It will be easier for you to ask questions in the future and also easier for other people to read, understand and answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(x,E) \leq d(x,e) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,e) \, \forall e \in E$. Take infimum over $e$ to get $d(x,E) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,E)$. Similarly, $d(y,E) \leq d(x,y)+d(x,E)$. Putting these together we get $|d(x,E)-d(y,E)|\leq d(x,y)$. So you can take $\delta =\epsilon$ in the definition of continuity.